# Write a resumable loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a test with the following structure:

```py
def test_foo(test_cases):
    for case in test_cases:
        run_test(case)
```

Each `run_test` is fairly slow, and if a case failed, calling the test again will start the loop from the beginning.

So instead, I keep track of last failed loop variable in a state file, like this:

```py
def test_foo(test_cases, state_file):
    states_dic = load_state_file(state_file)
    for case in itertools.dropwhile(
            lambda c : 'foo' in state_dic and state_dic['foo'] != c,
            test_cases):
        states_dic['foo'] = case
        try:
            run_test(case)
        except Exception:
            save_state_file(states_dic, state_file)
            raise
    states_dic.pop('foo', None)
    save_state_file(states_dic, state_file)
```

I am wondering if there is more generic way to implement a resume-from-state loop. So far what I have come up with is this pattern:

```py
def test_foo(test_cases, state_file):
    with ResumableIterator(test_cases, 'foo', state_file) as itercases:
        for case in itercases:
            run_test(case)
```

where `ResumableIterator` is a context manager that would keep track of loading and saving the state `'foo'` from/to `state_file`.  It would yield an iterator constructed from the first argument that keeps track of the last value it emitted so that when the loop exceptions out, it saves the last emitted value in the state file.  Any better ideas?

Comment: could this be a job for a coroutine? have you considered those?

Comment: Can't you just `yield`?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a slice? `for case in test_cases[lastcase+1:]` to start from the next case?

Comment: Is it not possible to keep running the rest of the tests even if one fails? I'd imagine `try-except` is all you need. Since you want to resume from the failed test, I figure there is no dependency issues.

Comment: Adding to @gill's point: you could return the list of failed tests and pass them to the next call of test_foo.

Comment: @gill, @Dirk  Yes it is possible to do that. I do use that pattern in some tests.  But for reason very specific to a few of my tests, `test_cases` are not just list of independent cases.  Usually some later cases are guaranteed to fail when an earlier case fail.  So it is usually more efficient for me to terminate the test at first failed case, quickly fix the problem (usually just minor parameter changes), and resume the test.

Comment: @timgeb that is a very interesting idea. I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is better than your context manager approach, but it's probably a little simpler, with only one `run` instead of `__enter__` and (the usually boring) `__exit__`.

```
# python 3
class TestRunner:

    def __init__(self, *test_cases):
        self.queue = list(test_cases)

    def run(self):
        for i, case in enumerate(self.queue):
            try:
                run_test(case)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                self.queue = self.queue[i:]
                break
```

For demo purpose, let's say

```
def run_test(case):
    case()

runner = TestRunner(
    lambda: print('case 1'),
    lambda: print('case 2'),
    lambda: print(im_not_defined),
    lambda: print('case 4')
)
```

Then you just call the `run` method to run the tests:

```
>>> runner.run()
case 1
case 2
name 'im_not_defined' is not defined
>>> runner.run()  # resume from last failure; will fail again since we didn't fix it
name 'im_not_defined' is not defined
>>> runner.queue[0] = lambda: print('case 3 fixed')
>>> runner.run()
case 3 fixed
case 4
```